# How to remove all properties from a nested array without change the individual array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to remove all properties from a nested array without change the individual array like `childArray1  = []` ?

```
Example:

childArray1 = ["test0"]
childArray2 = ["test1"]
childArray3 = ["test2"]


masterarray = [childArray1, chilArray2, childArray3]
```

Comment: *"without change the individual array"* is a bit ambiguous. Explain in more detail

Comment: The nested array *is* the individual array. Altering from any location changes the same array. You'd need to make a new array with or without the members you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
masterarray[1]= []
```

This should remove all elements from there.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a 2d array. You can find out more about them here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Creating_a_two-dimensional_array

In your case, it is impossible to clear the first element of `masterarry` without either also clearing the first array or changing the reference in `masterarray`.

```js
masterarray[0] = []; // changes reference
masterarray[0].length = 0; // clears both, keeps same reference
```

Comment: That will alter the original array, which is what the OP does not want. And that's not equivalent to `childArray1 = []`

Comment: @slappy I fixed it. It was unclear what OP wanted. I thought they meant not to alter masterarray.